# ajax execute by form id doesn't works if create html5 tags inside form

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2, commandlink

I have a datatable and form. Both are wrapped by html5 section tag. The table rendered correctly for edit, delete and cancel edit options, but doesn't work with save (save edits) and add new record(f:ajax execute).

I'm so new in JSF, so i can't understand very well how works ajax here.

I'm using JSF 2.2 (Mojarra) and GlassFish 4.1

[image]

Facelet:

```
<h:form id="toDoForm">
    <!--  todo table -->
    <section class="todo-table">
        <h:dataTable id="toDoTable" value="#{toDoBean.toDoList}" var="toDo" styleClass="table">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="ToDo name"/></f:facet>
                <h:inputText value="#{toDo.name}" rendered="#{toDo.editable}"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{toDo.name}" rendered="#{not toDo.editable}"/>
            </h:column>
            <!-- action command links -->
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Actions"/></f:facet>
                <h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{toDoBean.edit(toDo)}" rendered="#{not toDo.editable}">
                    <f:ajax render="toDoForm:toDoTable"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink value="Save" action="#{toDoBean.save(toDo)}" rendered="#{toDo.editable}">
                    <f:ajax execute="toDoForm" render="toDoForm:toDoTable"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink value="Cancel" action="#{toDoBean.cancelEdit(toDo)}" rendered="#{toDo.editable}">
                    <f:ajax render="toDoForm:toDoTable"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{toDoBean.delete(toDo)}" rendered="#{not toDo.editable}">
                    <f:ajax render="toDoForm:toDoTable"/>
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    </section>
    <!-- new toDo -->
    <section class="new-todo">
        <section class="frm-group">
            <h:outputLabel for="todo-name" value="ToDo name"/>
            <h:inputText id="todo-name" p:placeholder="Some task here..." value="#{toDoBean.toDo.name}"/>
        </section>
        <section class="frm-group">
            <h:outputLabel for="todo-date" value="Limit date"/>
            <h:inputText id="todo-date" p:placeholder="dd-MM-yyyy" value="#{toDoBean.toDo.expDate}"/>
        </section>
        <!-- just for add a fontawesome icon to button -->
        <button type="submit" jsf:action="toDoBean.add()">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            Add record
            <f:ajax execute="toDoForm" render="toDoForm:toDoTable"/>
        </button>
    </section>
</h:form>
```

**UPDATE**

The developer tools shows the ajax request:

[image]

Request headers

[image]

The response of ajax request is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="toDoForm:toDoTable"><![CDATA[<table id="toDoForm:toDoTable" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">ToDo name</th>
    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Learn JSF 2.2</td>
    <td><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:0:j_idt17" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Edit</a><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:0:j_idt20" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Learn CDI</td>
    <td><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:1:j_idt17" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Edit</a><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:1:j_idt20" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Learn JPA 2.1</td>
    <td><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:2:j_idt17" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Edit</a><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:2:j_idt20" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Learn WebSockets</td>
    <td><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:3:j_idt17" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Edit</a><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:3:j_idt20" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Learn EJB 3.1</td>
    <td><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:4:j_idt17" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Edit</a><a id="toDoForm:toDoTable:4:j_idt20" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'toDoForm:toDoTable');return false">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    ]]></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[758921174082037358:-1177618745060004189]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Some info you could add to your question: when you click "Save" or "Add record", does an AJAX event fire? If so, does the response contain errors? (AJAX errors are not always rendered.) Check your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Post updated with AJAX details.

Comment: Looks good, but check the "Response" tab in that image you posted. You'll see the XML that JSF is replying with. Sometimes it actually includes AJAX error messages that don't get rendered.

Comment: Thanks. Post updated with the response.

Comment: Are you really implying that it works fine once you remove "HTML5 tags" or replace them by "HTML4" equivalents? This is impossible as all that HTML5 buzz is only relevant in client side, not server side. JSF merely considers it as template text. This looks too much like a classic bean scope and/or business-logic-in-getter-method-on-an-entity-without-equals problem (i.e. datamodel preserving is broken as per point 4 of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183)

Comment: Based on what you've posted, BalusC is probably right about the problem. Note that the response XML does not contain "Go to gym", which is what you tried to save. This suggests that the model wasn't updated with the new data. (He's also right about your question title: you've made it sound like if you remove the HTML5 elements, everything works.)

Comment: Apparently validation has failed in that section? You basically placed two different forms in very same `<h:form>`. Split them in their own `<h:form>` and read server logs and/or add `<h:messages>` to get notified of any missing conversion/validation errors. And, please learn how to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) and to write correct question titles. The current one doesn't make any sense.